# Obtain Gradient of values against time stamp python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a df, self.meter_readings, where the index is datetime values and there is a column of numbers, as below:

```
self.meter_readings['PointProduction']
2012-03     7707.443
2012-04     9595.481
2012-05     5923.493
2012-06     4813.446
2012-07     5384.159
2012-08     4108.496
2012-09     6370.271
2012-10     8829.357
2012-11     7495.700
2012-12    13709.940
2013-01     6148.129
2013-02     7249.951
2013-03     6546.819
2013-04     7290.730
2013-05     5056.485
Freq: M, Name: PointProduction, dtype: float64
```

I want to get the gradient of PointProduction against time. i.e. y=PointProduction x=time. I'm currently trying to obtain m using a linear regression:

```
 m,c,r,x,y = stats.linregress(list(self.meter_readings.index),list(self.meter_readings['PointProduction']))
```

However I am getting an error:

```
 raise TypeError(other).
```

This is seemingly due to the formation of the x-axis as timestamps as oppose to just numbers.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try converting each Timestamp to Gregorian ordinal: `linregress` should then work with your `freq='M'` `index`.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

data = [
7707.443,
 9595.481,
 5923.493,
 4813.446,
 5384.159,
 4108.496,
 6370.271,
 8829.357,
 7495.700,
13709.940,
 6148.129,
 7249.951,
 6546.819,
 7290.730,
 5056.485
 ]

period_index = pd.period_range(start='2012-03', periods=len(data), freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, 
              index=period_index,
              columns=['PointProduction'])

# these ordinals are months since the start of the Unix epoch                   
df['ords'] = [tstamp.ordinal for tstamp in df.index]
m,c,r,x,y = stats.linregress(list(df.ords),
                             list(df['PointProduction']))
```

Comment: Thanks lb n-plus-1. This looks good and I thought it would work, but there still seems to be something different about how my data is indexed to your example above, as I'm getting an attribute error: AttributeError: 'Period' object has no attribute 'toordinal'.

Comment: @vbastrangledpython I've updated my answer to be compatible with a `PeriodIndex`d timeseries.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the datetimestamps in the x-axis as epoch time in seconds.

If the indexes are in datetime objects you need to convert them to epoch time, for example if ts is a datetime object the following function does the conversion

```
ts_epoch = int(ts.strftime('%s'))
```

This is an example of piece of code that could it be good for you, for converting the index column into epoch seconds:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=5, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

t =  ts.index
print [int(t[x].strftime('%s')) for x in range(len(t)) ]
```

This code is fully working on python2.7.

For using this piece of code on your problem, the solution could be the following:

```
t =  self.meter_readings.index
indexes = [int(t[x].strftime('%s')) for x in range(len(t)) ]

m,c,r,x,y = stats.linregress(indexes,list(self.meter_readings['PointProduction']))
```

Comment: Thanks TommasoF, my index is not strings however, but rather timestamps already, of the form Period('2013-01', 'M').

Comment: Hi TommasoF, for some weird reason the print statement makes my interpreter crash. I've tried to work out why this is by running your code but that doesn't seem to run, it gives the error: ValueError: Invalid format string. This may be a mistake on my end but I think I'm running the lines as above. Does this work for you? Many thanks.

Comment: The code is fully working on my side. I've added an import and specified the python version.

Comment: Sorry I tried to but my reputation is too low. I'll vote it up once my reputation is higher.